# lvm semantics compared with Mac OS container volumes - sharing storage between logical volumes?

Tags: macos, lvm, lvm2, zpool

I'm very new to lvm, and have simultaneously understood how Mac OS container disks work.

I'm very happy with Mac OS container disk semantics - I don't have to think how much space to allocate. I just create whatever volumes I want, and space gets magically allocated if I add files to a particular volume.

I assumed lvm would be the same but after creating a volume group `vg1` that fills 100% of my disk, and creating a logical volume `/dev/vg1/photos` that is permitted to use 100% of the volume group, I cannot create a second disk `/dev/vg1/videos` that similarly has the potential to use the entire physical volume for its own contents (if I don't put anything in the `/dev/vg1/photos` logical volume).

```
sudo vgcreate vg1 /dev/sdf1
sudo lvcreate -n photos -l 2.73T vg1
sudo lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n photos vg1
mkdir /mnt/photos
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg1/photos
sudo mount /dev/vg1/photos /mnt/photos

## Error - no unused space in volume group vg1
sudo lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n videos vg1
```

Am I correct in saying lvm's semantics are not identical to Mac OS volumes in this respect? In LVM, two logical volumes cannot automatically grab space from the same volume group without explicit, exclusive pre-allocation?

Answer (score 1):

#### ZFS is a closer equivalent to Mac OS CoreStorage volumes

The automatic pooling of storage space as illustrated in the OP can be achieved like this:

```
sudo apt install -y zfsutils-linux
sudo zpool create new-pool /dev/sdl11
sudo zpool status
sudo zfs create -o mountpoint=/mnt/audio new-pool/audio
sudo zfs create -o mountpoint=/mnt/books new-pool/books
# zfs mount new-pool/books
zfs list -o name,mountpoint
df
```

> Lightweight filesystem creation
>
> In ZFS, filesystem manipulation within
> a storage pool is easier than volume manipulation within a traditional
> filesystem; the time and effort required to create or expand a ZFS
> filesystem is closer to that of making a new directory than it is to
> volume manipulation in some other systems.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#Lightweight_filesystem_creation

#### Related reading

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_virtualization#Host-based

Answer (score 0):

I think my understanding is going to evolve but here is what I see so far:

- Mac OS uses what LVM calls *thin volumes* with *autoextend* (https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-enable-thin-lvm-automatic-extension/)

> A thick volume is always fully-provisioned, which means that all of
> the capacity is allocated when the volume is created. A thin volume is
> always thinly-provisioned, which means that the capacity is allocated
> as the data is being written to the volume.

Contrary to what wikipedia says (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Storage#Notes - I think this is outdated).

#### Terminology

| Mac OS | Linux LVM |
| --- | --- |
| Physical Disk | Physical Volume |
| Container | Volume Group |
| Volume | Logical Volume |

Though in Mac OS 11 I think "Container" has been replaced with "Volume Group" in the `Disk Utillity.app` list.

Comment: As I research this more, the above understanding may be incorrect. ZFS is closer to Apple CoreStorage. LVM is an older technology that doesn't really correlate.

Comment: No, I think LVM thin volumes fit perfectly fine. They are block devices, just like CoreStorage volumes. With ZFS, only ZFS volume are similar.